# Modeling for 3D Printing (Sorry, I'm new to Blender)

Tags: 3d-printing

I just got a 3D printer and I've been able to use Blender to modify some existing parts, but my brother-in-law asked me to print this part for him for his RC helicopter and I have no clue how to model it.  Any hints to get me started would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please use a title that reflects the content of the question. It should be succinct, unique and identifying, and summarize what the issue is so that users can at a glance broadly understand what your post is about before opening it. Use the [edit] link below your post and avoid any emojis salutations or extraneous text not essential to the question. Remember, your title is the first thing potential visitors will see, and will weight heavily on their decision to open your question, which will directly affect the number of answers you might get.

Comment: You need to get a good set of Vernier Calipers to measure it, don't cheap out on this tool.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the adventure sounds like you need some modeling help here's a good start.  Watch the entire series.  It's helped me.

Learn Precision Modeling & Blender 2.9+ / 3.0 | Series Intro - The Starting Point | Part - 1

https://youtu.be/83yNYScsRPI